# Metadata requests in Kafka producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

How many metadata requests will Kafka producer make? one per message or one per batch or one per partition?

How the acknowledgements will be sent to produce by Kafka ? one at a time or as a whole list or list per each leader?

Answer (score 3):

The first time the producer makes a metadata request is when it connects to the bootstrap servers that you set in the client configuration. Of course, it can be just one broker or more but not necessarily all the brokers in the cluster (so the metadata request is not for each broker). In this way, the producer gets information about where are the topics that it wants to send messages.
During its life, more metadata requests can be done when it receives an error connecting to the broker leader for the partition it's writing, in this case, it needs to know which broker is the new leader for connecting to it (if not connected yet for other topics) and starting to send.

Answer (score 1):

> How many metadata requests will Kafka producer make? one per message or one per batch or one per partition?

Usually one per broker, to find out the partition leaders.
Could be more if the whole send process takes a lot of time and your metadata on producer side expires (the property is called `metadata.timeout.ms` or so).

> How the acknowledgements will be sent to produce by Kafka ? one at a time or as a whole list or list per each leader?

Produce requests are sent only to leaders.
As they contain batches of records, you will get a `ProduceResponse` per batch.

Comment: What happens if the metadata actually times out? Does it disconnect and reconnect? Or does it just request the metadata again in the same connection?